# C# to Automate an ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation

I have a website to which I need to pass 4 parameters and then extract data programmatically but there is a big problem. The website is built into ASP.NET with FORM inside AJAX. So, I can fill one field programmatically and then I fill second field. There is a need to click a button in order to fill third field so I press button programmatically then. The problem is that when I click the button, the second fill gets empty before calling the button event and causes error.

So is there a way I can sharply fill fields without causing errors?

Comment: Do you have any control over the website? Like can you change any code in the web site? Or can't you think of a service on the other side in place of the web page?

Comment: I am not the actual owner of the target site. Even I need to submit form and I can't use C# HTTPWebRequest because I don't know the URL to post to. I just have a form in front of me which I can open in browser and fill the fields and then submit.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at web automation library such as [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) - this lets you do this kind of interaction.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Oded and would like to add that as an alternative [Selenium RC](http://selenium-rc.seleniumhq.org/) in combination with [NUnit](http://nunit.org) might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe IRobotSoft web scraper can do this kind of work.  You will use two form filling actions, and add a Click action between them.